# Citation for positive Ricci curvature

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups

Does anyone know a citeable source where it is shown that the Ricci curvature of SU(n) is strictly positive? I can sketch the proof but I need to shorten my notes.

Thanks,

Stefan

Comment: Yes, it is in the accepted answer to this discussion: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67445/ricci-curvature-of-the-symplectic-group

Answer (score 4):

This (freely available!) [article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0001-8708%2876%2980002-3) by Milnor contains many results about curvature of left-invariant metrics on Lie groups.

In particular, lemma 2.1 implies that a compact semi-simple Lie group (such as yours) with a bi-invariant metric has strictly positive Ricci curvature.

Alternatively, formula (7.3) computes the sectional curvature of a bi-invariant metric as $\langle[x,y],[x,y]\rangle/4$ in the tangent plane with orthonormal basis $x,y$ inside the Lie algebra. This gives $Ric>0$ outside of the center of the Lie algebra.

ADDED: see also [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/31200/6451) to a related post for a textbook reference.